# How do I disable automatic monitor detection and adjustment of displays?

Tags: 11.10, xorg, display, dell, vga

I am running 11.10 on an Dell Mini 9 (Inspiron 910). When I connect VGA or close the lid the computer automatically detects the change and adjusts the displays.

How can I disable this?

Comment: Are you running Unity?